# Why use TestNG annotations like @BeforeSuite when you have listeners which do the same?

Tags: java, annotations, testng, listener

I've always used TestNG annotations like @BeforeSuite, @BeforeClass etc. in my tests.
But lately, I've been reading about TestNG listeners, and I can't help but feel most of the methods these listeners provide do exactly the same things as some of the annotations.

For example: 
@BeforeSuite seems to be the same as ISuiteListener.onStart()
@BeforeMethod seems the same as IInvokedMethodListener.beforeInvocation().

So, why do we have these methods that pretty much do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The methods are intended to be used by the environment running the test, not by the test itself. For example, an IDE can add an ISuiteListener and update the status of running the tests shown in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

They are used just to customize the configuration for all levels like BeforeMethod,Class etc.

For example if you want different configuration in

> @BeforeMethod

for different classes then you will use @BeforeMethod in each class with some different configuration, that configuration will be limited to that class and its methods only and not for all methods or tests in the complete suite.
If you use it in listeners then it will be common to all classes and methods.
Generally listeners annotations are used to perform a common function that is required for all classes and methods.
For example , starting logging at the beginning of tests or at suite start, capturing screenshot at the end of test case etc.

Same is for , i.e different configuration for different class and not a common configuration.

> @BeforeClass

Hope it might answer your question.